# Are there National Drinking Holidays?

Tags: drinking, holidays

What are the National Drinking Holidays? And, for what respective country? i.e.: Oktoberfest for Germany

Comment: What do you mean by holidays? Oktoberfest is not holidays at all!

Comment: Does the local tradition of [Tibb's Eve](http://www.southerngazette.ca/news/2010/7/8/the-origins-of-tibb-s-eve-1521238.html)  on December 23 (day before Christmas Eve) in Newfoundland and Labrador (Canada) count?

Comment: @Altbier. Holidays, to me, are any series of days where it,s deemed worthy to celebrate. You would at least consider oktoberfest a celebration, right?

Comment: @Ken. Yep, you know it! :)

Comment: So how are "drinking holidays" distinguished from normal "holidays" (e.g. New Year or Easter holidays)?

Comment: I imagine its simply because the day hadn,t already been taken for anything else. I believe it is true that most of the population doesn,t know about these days - i knew there were national holidays for drinking but i didn,t know about give a bum a drink day, for example. And, unfortunately for me, i don,t get off work for national beer day or new beer,s eve. :P

Comment: I don't think there are any holidays where the sole purpose is to drink in any country. I lived in Munich for a couple of years, while it's a festive occasion that last three weeks, it's not a national holiday. There is beer involved, but there is also food and amusement rides. There are towns in Germany and France and Italy that shut down to celebrate a harvest of grapes and lots of wine is consumed, but these are local not national

Comment: BTW Oktoberfest is NOT a **Drinking** Festival.

Comment: Ok, i get it. Bad example - we stupid americans tend to interpret it that way...

Comment: Cinco De Mayo for the United States

Answer (score 4):

In the United States, there are several Drinking Holidays. Here's a list from [this site:](http://www.ahistoryofdrinking.com/drink-holidays/) (I'm highlighting some of my favorites :)

> January
>
> ```
> National Hot Tea Month
> January 1: National Bloody Mary Day
> January 11: National Hot Toddy Day
> January 17: National Hot Buttered Rum Day
> January 17:  **National Bootlegger’s Day**
> January 18: National Gourmet Coffee Day
> January 24: Beer Can Appreciation Day
> January 25: National Irish Coffee Day
> January 31: National Hot Chocolate Day, Brandy Alexander Day
> ```
>
> February
>
> ```
> 3rd Weekend of February: National Margarita Weekend
> February 17 : National Cafe’ Au Lait Day
> February 18: National “Drink Wine” Day
> February 22: National Margarita Day
> February 27: National Kahlua Day
> ```
>
> March
>
> ```
> National Caffeine Awareness Month
> March 3:  National Mulled Wine Day
> March 17: St. Patrick’s Day
> March 20: Bock Beer Day
> March 27: National World Whisky Day
> ```
>
> April
>
> ```
> **April 6: New Beer’s Eve
> April 7: National Beer Day**
> April 14: National Rum Day
> April 17: World Malbec Day
> April 19: National Amaretto Day
> ```
>
> May
>
> ```
> First Saturday in May: National Homebrew Day
> The 3rd Monday of May and the rest of the week: American Craft Beer Week
> May 4: National Homebrew Day, National Orange Juice Day
> May 5: Cinco de Mayo
> May 6:  Beverage Day
> May 8: Have a Coke Day
> May 13: World Cocktail Day
> May 16: National Mimosa Day
> May 21: World Whisky Day
> May 25: National Wine Day
> May 30: National Mint Julep Day
> ```
>
> June
>
> ```
> National Iced Tea Month
> June 1-7: Negroni Week
> June 4: Cognac Day
> June 5: Moonshine Day
> June 6: **National Give a Bum a Drink Day**
> June 10: National Iced-Tea Day
> June 11: National Gin Day
> June 11: National Black Cow Day
> June 14: Bourbon Day
> June 19: National Martini Day
> June 20: National Vanilla Milkshake Day
> June 27: National Orange Blossom Day
> June 30: National Mai Tai Day
> ```
>
> July
>
> ```
> National Pickle Month
> July 2 : National Anisette Day
> July 10: Pina Colada Day
> July 11: National Mojito Day
> July 14: National Grand Marnier Day
> July 19: National Daiquiri Day
> July 24: National Tequila Day
> July 25: National Wine and Cheese Day
> July 27: National Scotch Day
> ```
>
> August
>
> ```
> August 5: **International Beer Day**
> August 6: National Root Beer Float Day
> August 7: National IPA Day, International Beer Day
> August 16: National Rum Day
> August 20: National Lemonade Day
> August 21: National Sweet Tea Day
> August 22: National Spumoni Day
> August 25: National Whiskey Sour Day
> August 28: National Red Wine Day
> August 29: Lemon Juice Day
> ```
>
> September
>
> ```
> September 7: **National Beer Lover’s Day**
> September 12 : National Chocolate Milkshake Day
> September 15: National Creme de Menthe Day
> September 20 : National Punch Day / Rum Punch Day
> September 27: National Chocolate Milk Day
> September 28: **National Drink a Beer Day**
> September 29: National Coffee Day
> September 29: National Mocha Day
> September 30: National Mulled Cider Day
> ```
>
> October
>
> ```
> National Applejack Month
> Second Weekend in October: National Kegger Weekend
> October 1: National Pumpkin Spice Day
> October 4: National Vodka Day
> October 7: National Frappe Day
> October 15: National Red Wine Day
> October 16: National Liqueur Day
> October 19: National Gin and Tonic Day
> October 20 : National Brandied Fruit Day
> October 21: National Mezcal Day
> October 27: **American Beer Day**
> ```
>
> November
>
> ```
> November 7: World Gin Day
> November 8 : National Cappuccino Day
> November 8: National Harvey Wallbanger Day
> November 12: National Happy Hour Day
> November 14: National Pickle ‘Appreciation’ Day
> November 18: National Apple Cider Day
> November 19: National Macchiato Day
> November 20: National Beaujolais Day
> November 23: National Espresso Day
> ```
>
> December
>
> ```
> December 3: National Peppermint Latte Day
> December 3: National Rhubarb Vodka Day
> December 5 : **Repeal of Prohibition Day**
> December 10: National Lager Day
> December 12: National Cocoa Day
> December 13: National Screwdriver Day
> December 20: National Sangria Day
> December 24: National Egg Nog Day
> December 31: National Champagne Day
> ```

Here is [another calender](http://mixologydiary.com/national-drink-days-calendar/) and [here's another.](http://intoxicologist.net/2016/01/drinking-holidays-2016/)

Answer (score 2):

Now there is the Newfoundland thing. You know [Tibb's Eve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibb's_Eve) (sometime called St Tibb's Eve) which occurs in Newfoundland and Labrador every December 23, on the eve of Christmas Eve.

> Tibb’s Eve. Tipp’s Eve. Tip’s Eve. Even Tipsy Eve. It doesn’t matter what you call it – it’s December 23rd in Newfoundland and it’s time to have a drink.
>
> Every year on the eve of Christmas Eve people in Newfoundland get the party started. Family and friends are home from the mainland and that calls for a tipple or two. Downtown is on wheels and it’s usually a good time to catch a show. All the best bands have gigs on the go. But how did this yearly party night begin?
>
> In the lead up to the holidays, Advent is a sober, religious time of year. It’s all about prepping and waiting for the celebration. Denying yourself so that you can really give’r when the big day arrives. By the time Christmas actually rolls around, the good people of Newfoundland are jonesing for a drink. It used to be that they would wait until Christmas Day to imbibe but sometime in the mid-20th century people had had enough and made up the holiday of Tibb’s Eve as an excuse to crack open the bottle two days early.
>
> Why Tibb’s Eve?
>
> Why Tibb? The word is archaic slang for a promiscuous woman. Tibb was often used as the name of a loose-moraled woman in 17th century English plays – she was often the comic relief. Adults could refer to Saint Tibb, knowing it would go over the heads of kids, who thought she was a real saint. [Tibb’s Eve: A Newfoundland Thing](http://www.suitcaseandheels.com/tibbs-eve-a-newfoundland-thing/)

Here is an other interesting article on Tibb's Eve: [The origins of Tibb's Eve](http://www.southerngazette.ca/news/2010/7/8/the-origins-of-tibb-s-eve-1521238.html)

**Merry Christmas everyone!**

Comment: I love it! US needs to adopt this one asap.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible answer for this question could be **Drunkard's Thursday**.

It is celebrated on the Thursday before [Ash Wednesday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_Wednesday) by Syrian Catholics.

> Syrian Catholics have celebrated the day as "Drunkard's Thursday" with dolmas as the traditional food. - [Fat Thursday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Thursday)

[image: Pre-Lenten Holidays]

[Pre-Lenten Holidays](https://www.newspapers.com/clip/4220329/prelenten_holidays_1960/)

Answer (score 2):

In The Netherlands we have Kingsday.

> King’s Day may well be the best party in Holland. On 27 April, we celebrate King Willem Alexander’s birthday with music, street parties, flea markets, and fun fairs. The king himself travels through the country with his family. On the night before King’s Day, King’s Night is celebrated with music shows in The Hague and other cities and the nation’s biggest flea (‘free’) market in Utrecht.

Every city has it's own big parties and fleamarkets. Here in Groningen, king's night is very popular and probably one of the busiest nights in the bars.

Answer (score 2):

Adding yet another possibility for everyone, but this time I would like to make the national drinking day an international drinking day: [International Beer Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Beer_Day) (IBD).

> International Beer Day (IBD) is a celebration on the **first Friday of every August** founded in 2007 in Santa Cruz, California. Since its inception, International Beer Day has grown from a small localized event in the western United States into a worldwide celebration spanning 207 cities, 50 countries and 6 continents. Specifically, International Beer Day has three declared purposes:
>
> 1.To gather with friends and enjoy the taste of beer.
>
> 2.To celebrate those responsible for brewing and serving beer.
>
> 3.To unite the world under the banner of beer, by celebrating the beers of all nations together on a single day.
>
> **Popularity**
>
> International Beer Day began as a celebration at the founders’ local bar, but has since expanded to become a worldwide event. Celebrations are planned throughout the United States as well as in Argentina, Armenia, Australia, Austria, Belgium, Brazil, Bulgaria, Canada, Colombia, Costa Rica, El Salvador, England, France, Greece, Honduras, Hong Kong, Hungary, India, Ireland, Israel, Italy, Japan, Latvia, Lebanon, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Macedonia, Malaysia, Mexico, New Zealand, Nicaragua, Norway, Peru, Poland, Portugal, Puerto Rico, Romania, Scotland, Serbia, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, South Africa, Spain, Sri Lanka, Sweden, Thailand, the Philippines, Turkey, Uganda, United Arab Emirates, Uruguay, Vanuatu, and Venezuela.